# Синтез речи в Android

Tags: java, android, синтезатор-речи

Чем отличается `TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD` от `TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH`?

Answer (score 5):

`TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH` — флаг, обозначающий, что при добавлении новой фразы текущую необходимо прервать и начать воспроизведение добавленной. Если вы хотите составить очередь из фраз, следует использовать вместо этого флаг `TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD`.